# Image format issue MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have 1 bit depth images :
A = grayscale intensity images : UINT8
B = image A segmented with `im2bw` and threshold b : LOGICAL
C = image A segmented with `im2bw` and threshold c : LOGICAL
D = image A segmented with `im2bw` and threshold d : LOGICAL
E = resulting image : DOUBLE

I introduce a loop where I compare B, C, D (`if/else`) and according to the result E is filled with values of A or B.
Before that I created `E=ones(800,800);`

I read that `uint8` have values between 0 and 255 (8bit) and `double` has floating point on 64 bit (I don't know what that means).
The fact is that E doesn't look like it should and if I change A or E to `double` or `uint8`, either I have a whole white image or a really weird image.

I'm guessing that I have issues with the images format but I don't jnow HOW or WHERE.

Thank you,

Sarah

Comment: before triying anything, diplay the image as `imshow(img,[])`. If an image is double on Matlab, it expects the image to be in range 0-1. so if you want to put an `uint8` value in the image, insert it by dividing by 255.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Thanks for the hint but dividing the value of A to be inserted by 255 or not doesn't change the image E. Image E is still a black and white (0,1) images while it should contain grayscale value coming from A. Any other idea ?

Comment: Yes, the one I suggested .... If E is double, then it contains grayscale values from 0-1 (from 0-1 means it contains 0.452 also!). So if you want E to be double, then you need to scale the values of A when saving it on E. For example: `E(4,5)= 145/255`. This will make Matlab plot it rigth, beacuse if the value on E is hihger than 1 matlab will "round it" to 1 allways.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. I actually found my way out, I created E as uint8 so A can fill it easely and I created a new image F uint8 made of B logical value so I can use F to fill E.

Comment: Good! Thenk polease, close the question or answer your own question ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found my way out, I created E as `uint8` so A can fill it easely.
I also created a new image 'F' `uint8` made of B `logical` value so I can use F (coming from B) to fill E.